# Not showing integer value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why its showing the variable as a bool and not an integer like it should be.

The kow_auth config file is autoloaded.

library:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "max_attempts:";
var_dump($this->ci->config->item('login_max_attempts', 'kow_auth'));
echo "</pre>";
```

kow_auth config file

```
http://pastebin.com/9KMEn4Uf
```

Comment: can you show how you get the config file's content ? seems like the error is here

Comment: Does `$this->ci->config->item('login_max_attempts')` work?

Comment: How is your `$ci` defined on your controller?

Comment: @Panique I posted entire config file

Comment: Okay so for some reason when I take off the kow_auth part and post what Yan suggested it reports back the correct value. Why is that though. I thought I had to attach the name of the config file.

Comment: Have you read the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the second parameter: `kow_auth`

It is trying to retrieve `login_max_attempts` from a array called `kow_auth` and that doesn't exist on your config file.

You can create configurations like this:

```
$config['kow_auth']['login_by_username'] = TRUE;
$config['kow_auth']['login_by_email'] = FALSE;
$config['kow_auth']['login_max_attempts'] = 5;
$config['kow_auth']['login_attempt_expire'] = 60*60*24;
```

This way it should work with your second parameter.

Docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this bool false or true ? Let me guess: false !? ;)
Then it might be that you simply don't get the content of `$config['login_max_attempts']`. `var_dump` gives out an `false` because there is not such variable/object defined on your code with that name.

Comment: I keep having issues with this part of it. Creating custom config files and my project not getting those values from the config file. But yes I am getting false back.